# Cant fix dependecy problems on Ubuntu 12.04 libcanberra-gtk

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, apt-get

Cant install any package neither "apt-get upgrade" due dependencies errors on libcanberra-gtk0

apt-get check

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-session-canberra : Breaks: libcanberra-gtk0 (< 0.28-4) but 0.28-3ubuntu3 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

apt-get -f install

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libcanberra-gtk0
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libcanberra-gtk0
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 585 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/17.1 kB of archives.
After this operation, 9,216 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcanberra-gtk0:i386:
 gnome-session-canberra (0.28-4) breaks libcanberra-gtk0 (<< 0.28-4) and is unpacked but not configured.
  Version of libcanberra-gtk0:i386 to be configured is 0.28-3ubuntu3.
dpkg: error processing libcanberra-gtk0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-session-canberra:
 gnome-session-canberra depends on libcanberra-gtk0; however:
  Package libcanberra-gtk0:i386 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing gnome-session-canberra (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
configured to not write apport reports
                                      Errors were encountered while processing:
 libcanberra-gtk0:i386
 gnome-session-canberra
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Trying to install something
apt-get install -f aptitude

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 aptitude : Depends: libboost-iostreams1.49.0 (>= 1.49.0-1) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libcwidget3 but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libept1.4.12 but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: aptitude-doc-en but it is not going to be installed or
                        aptitude-doc
            Recommends: libparse-debianchangelog-perl but it is not going to be installed
 gnome-session-canberra : Breaks: libcanberra-gtk0 (< 0.28-4) but 0.28-3ubuntu3 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

How i can reinstall the package?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question might be better suited for www.askubuntu.com.  In the meantime, you might want to download and install the package manually, thus bypassing aptitude.

Comment: "Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages ..." Did you try this?

Comment: yes, but no luck ( second command in post )

Comment: I had imcompatible apt sources in /etc/apt/apt.d/
Deleting all do the job.

Comment: If you solved the problem, you should write the solution as an answer and accept it.  You will not earn any point, but it will make the site better.

Answer (score 0):

You have to look for the specified package in launchpad, so for `libcanberra-gtk0` you need to got [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/i386/libcanberra-gtk0), but you might want to change to another ubuntu version and architecture.

Then you need to retype `sudo apt-get -f install` and it's possible you keep getting error messages for libs dependencies, and again you have to repeat the process.

However, this method is also dangerous because it also affects the way ubuntu gets version upgraded... since it can't resolve these packs.